# One of functions in class not working?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I would like to know why are my variables not changing in the `def moving(self)` method? Am I missing something? In this object the snake should move (up, down, left, right) depending on the `dir_x`, `dir_y`.

The code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
class Snake(object):

    def __init__ (self, x, y, dir_x, dir_y, con_x, con_y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.dir_x = dir_x
        self.dir_y = dir_y
        self.con_x = con_x
        self.con_y = con_y
        self.snakey = root.create_rectangle((self.x+243, self.y+243, self.x+251, self.y+251), fill = "#000000")
    def moving(self):
        if self.dir_x == 10:
            self.x = self.x + 10
            root.coords(self.snakey, self.x, self.y, self.dir_x, self.dir_y, self.con_x, self.con_y)
        if self.dir_x == -10:
            self.x = self.x - 10
            root.coords(self.snakey, self.x, self.y, self.dir_x, self.dir_y, self.con_x, self.con_y)
        if self.dir_y == 10:
            self.y = self.y + 10
            root.coords(self.snakey, self.x, self.y, self.dir_x, self.dir_y, self.con_x, self.con_y)
        if self.dir_y == -10:
            self.y = self.y - 10
            root.coords(self.snakey, self.x, self.y, self.dir_x, self.dir_y, self.con_x, self.con_y)

    def __str__ (self):
        return "<Snake x:%s y:%s dir_x:%s dir_y:%s con_x:%s con_y:%s>" % (self.x, self.y, self.dir_x, self.dir_y, self.con_x, self.con_y)
def moveup(event):
    global dy, dx
    dy = 10
    dx = 0
def movedown(event):
    global dy, dx
    dy = -10
    dx = 0
def moveleft(event):
    global dx, dy
    dx = -10
    dy = 0
def moveright(event):
    global dx, dy
    dx = 10
    dy = 0
win = Tk()
win.title("Snake")
root = Canvas(win, width = 493, height = 493, background = "white")
root.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
x = -1
d, c = 0, 0
xs, xy, dx, dy, cx, cy = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
for i in range(2, 492, 10):
    root.create_line((i, 1, i, 500), fill = "#BFBFBF")
    root.create_line((1, i, 500, i), fill = "#BFBFBF")
root.create_rectangle((2, 2, 493, 493), width = 4)
#S1 = Snake(xs, xy, dx, dy, cx, cy)
def Repeat():
    S1 = Snake(xs, xy, dx, dy, cx, cy)
    print("Tik", dx, dy)
    print (S1)
    root.after(500, Repeat)
Repeat()
root.bind("w", moveup)
root.bind("s", movedown)
root.bind("a", moveleft)
root.bind("d", moveright)
root.focus_set()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are sure that `moving` method is ever called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create the method `moving`, but never call it - it's never executed.
You probably want to call in in repeat. Like this:

```
def Repeat():
    S1 = Snake(xs, xy, dx, dy, cx, cy)
    S1.moving ()
    print("Tik", dx, dy)
    print (S1)
    root.after(500, Repeat)
```

But be warned that the variables will only change inside S1, and not outside - if you're creating it every call of `repeat`, you'll discard data like `S1.x` (and so the snake won't move)